Spring Security permitAll not allowing access
I have a single method that I want to allow both anonymous and authenticated access to.
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable());
        http.cors(customizer -> customizer.disable());
        return http.build();
    }

But when I register new User with POST method. I still get 401 error even though I used permitAll() for the "/user/register" endpoint
Can anyone help me?
Expected: I can access "/user/register" endpoint without being 401 error

Can you show the method that handles the "/user/register" request?


It would be good if you shared the logs but first verify that the the path "/user/register" is correct as defined in the controller.
You may also specify the the postmethod ".requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/register").permitAll()".
You may also try do allow anonymous access explicitly using "http.anonymous();


Thanks for your solutions

The path "/user/register" is correct in the controller
I try to specify the postmethod  ".requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/register").permitAll()". But I didn't work
In spring with the new version, i can not use "http.anonymous();

